# python gtk dark theme icon buttons

Tags: python, linux, themes, gtk3, cinnamon

After changing the theme on my Cinnamon Desktop to a dark theme (Adwaita-dark) a program that I wrote a while ago now displays the buttons incorrect. While e.g. in other programs like the file manager the color of the icons is now white they stay dark here.

[image: Button is dark mode but icon is light mode]

I created those buttons using `Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name()`:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk

...

button = Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name("document-new", 1)
```

Is there a way of making them automatically adapt their color to the currently active theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I ended up using a `*-symbolic` version of the icon.
According to [Gnome docs](https://wiki.gnome.org/Design/OS/SymbolicIcons)

> In the GNOME 3 designs we have identified a number of places where using a symbolic variant of a standard icon is desirable. Symbolic icons are usually low color or monochrome and intended to match the foreground font color. They may be used where a high color, detailed representation isn't warranted.

It means you would rather be using

```
button = Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name("document-new-symbolic", 1)
```